# Google One tap sign in shows lots of timeout errors

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-signin

new to github.

We were working to implement a simpler and faster way to login on our website. 
We recently implemented a sign in using **googleyolo api**.
I followed the steps mentioned 
[here](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/overview) .

After releasing it to users on our website, We are getting a lot of timeout errors.(50% of users who support this API are getting this error)
While testing the error was encountered about 10% of times.
I could not find any questions related to my problem.

Any help would be appreciated.
Could not find a repo of or contact page for this API, So i am posting here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timeouts usually happen on mobile devices where the network is slow. All calls to `googleyolo` API (`retrieve`, `hint`) time out after 3s to avoid delaying further execution on the app.

If most of your user base experience this issue, I recommend increasing the timeout:

```
// Set the timeout to 5s.
googleyolo.setTimeouts(5000);
```